# very buggy slow scroll (native to browser) when float:left is used in EE2 with some heavy javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-float, gallery, expressionengine

So I have created a gallery in expression engine2, which, frankly, I don't know too well, so I used lots of javascript to make up for it 
(if you'd advice any easier way to do this, I'll love you forever)

Peculiarly enough, when I use the float on my block link with pictures, the scrolling on the page starts going crazy.

```
<a href="#" class="popthisshit photoins" style=""><img height="170" src="'+quitenice[i]+'"></a>
```

I've isolated this quite precisely:

```
.photoins{ display:block; border:1px solid #666; height:140px; width:140px; overflow:hidden; margin:0px 0px 20px 20px; float:left;}
.photoins img{text-align:center; height: 240px; margin:-50% -50%;}
```

as soon as I use float: left; the page stops scrolling properly.
Remove it and it's fine..
__

Here's the code [don't be hatin plzktnx]

I begin with creating the array **quitenice** from the photos in the channel:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="galleries" disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" limit="1" status="open|closed"}
<script> 
var quitenice = new Array('{gallery_photos}{row_photo} ', '{/gallery_photos}');
```

But oh whyyyy, you may shout at a distance..
Because of the following:
Here I create the fake paginate in order to avoid using it, as it proved to be heavier..

```
var zero = 0;
var size = 25;
var somecount = 0;

for (var i=zero; i<size; i+=1) {
    somecount+=1;
    document.write('<a href="#" class="popthisshit photoins" style=""><img height="170" src="'+quitenice[i]+'"></a>');
};

var newzero=zero+size; 
var newsize = size+newzero;
```

so now we get the first set of 25 pictures. 
This is the picture anchor

```
document.write('<a href="#" class="morePics"></a>');
```

and, here's the infinite scroll:

```
$(function () {
             var $win = $(window);
             $win.scroll(function () {
                 if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
                    if(quitenice.length >=newsize){ 
                        for (var ii=newzero; ii<newsize; ii+=1) {
                            $('.morePics').before('<a href="#" class="popthisshit photoins"><img src="'+quitenice[ii]+'"></a>');        
                        };
                        newzero += size;
                        newsize +=size;
                    }else{  
                        for (var ii=newzero; ii< quitenice.length-1; ii+=1) {
                            $(this).before('<a href="#" class="popthisshit photoins"><img src="'+quitenice[ii]+'"></a>');
                        };
                        $('.morePics').before('<span class="ender"></span>');
                        newzero += size;
                        newsize +=size;
                    }; 
                 }
             });
         });

</script>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So remove the float: left, and it scrolls fine, but then adding bunch of position: absolutes in the javascript seems even further backwards.

I use bunch of sub libraries with 1.8.0 jQuery. I tried to change that and everything else, but it's the float: left that makes it buggy.
Help.

ps: popthisshit calls the super light lightbox, which also has little to do with the problem!

Comment: Really tough to help out on a problem like this with no viewable demo, think you could put one up? Also, wouldn't advise putting profanities in your source, unless this is a personal site for yourself.

Comment: Hi Austin, yes, you are right about profanities, that was uncalled for.. Here's the demo: http://themansioninc.com/index.php/v1/gallery_new/122, where .photoinc floats left and http://themansioninc.com/index.php/v1/gallery1/122, where it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when writing an infinite scroll script. The issue is that the scroll event fires at every small steo in each scroll. The solution, which I found in airbnb's InfinityJS, is to use an interval set at ~500 to check the difference in scroll since the last interval. Then run your `shouldShow` method based on the `scrollY`

```
var prevScroll = -1
window.setInterval(function () {
    currScroll = window.scrollY
    if (currScroll != prevScroll) {
        // check
    }
})
```

Comment: you see, the absurd thing about this is that it scrolls terribly without infinite scroll. I slashed the scroll out of the code and it was still buggy. The only thing that makes it not buggy is removing the float:left from .photoins css... it's absurd!